# Radio Button with value to be <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

Is this possible to have input type="text" as a value to radio button ?

I have 3 options on the input type radio button.

```
[ o Option 1, o Option 2, o Others ]
```

But instead of adding Others, I wanted it to be an `<input type="text">` wherein people can add in a specific value if they click this.

Comment: have an input checkbox before an input text

Comment: checkbox or radio buttons?

Comment: @Tsar Thanks for pointing this out. Radio Buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's not possible. But what you can do is. Take one textfield, make it hide. And when user clicks on other at that time show that textfield. Hope it will helps.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. I have thought of this too but it will break design style.

Answer (score -2):

All your checkboxes should have `name=something[]` in order to be sent to the server.

Add `input type=text name=something[]` - it's value will be included into the form data.

Comment: This is true if you have "multi-select" boxes (as opposed to "select one or the other" as this looks like) that you want to get as an array. However it is not correct that you need to do it to get it sent to the server.

Comment: Question was about 'checkboxes' this usually means multi-select.